# linux + uptime how to know the reboot date?

Tags: linux, redhat, boot, uptime

as all know with uptime we can capture the days that machine is up

```
# uptime
12:08:19 up 93 days, 14:12,  1 user,  load average: 0.38, 0.36, 0.40
```

what we actually need is to know the date of the reboot / restart

for example - **21/5/2016 12:98**

**uptime** command not have the right flags to do that , so maybe with other commands ?

but after google searching I not find what I want ,

So I will happy to get any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`who -b` will show the last boot time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to the nearest day with:

```
date -d "now - $(date | awk '{print $3}') days"
```

Further parsing of the output of date to extract the hours and minutes